# how do i assert a value of title of a webpage whose expected value comes from the excel sheet in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an excel sheet with some rows and column. I have to check the data from specific column to see if it matches the data from the page title. 
I am using java for this.

Comment: do u want to map webpage title to excel sheet name?

Comment: Something like that. To be more specific, I need to check if the page is loading the title according to title which is present in the excel's particular column

Comment: Read the title from excel sheet and store it in PageTitleReadFromExcel  and compare with current title as shown below
assertEquals(PageTitleReadFromExcel , driver.getTitle());

Comment: i'm not able to get the value for PageTitleReadFromExcel to be used for assert. And the value needs to be from a specific column and i have to iterate it for every row aswell

Comment: First I would recommend to create a separate library with methods for working with your excel files. Then, during test just use methods, to get a required value from excel and validate, that value from web page is the same as taken from excel.

Comment: @Ms.Salona Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your question to get more and accurate answers on it

Comment: @Dev. thankyou for the guidance sir. I will edit the question however, i have found the answer which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very subjective but I will answer as per my understanding.
You want to read Particular cell so I will not worry about iteration. Not sure if you are using .xls or .xlsx which may have affect or either be using XSS or HSS. I assume you are using .xlsx so will using XSS.

```
FileInputStream fileToRead = new FileInputStream(new File("yourfile.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileToRead);
```

now pass which sheet, which row and which column you want to read in the below section.

```
String cellValue = workbook.getSheetAt(sheet).getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
```

then add assert check if it matches the page title.

```
 Assert.assertEquals(cellValue, driver.getTitle());
```

Answer is based on assumptions so feel free to edit your question and I can also edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: You just have to add Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle, cellValue); to assert it.

Comment: @Sumit2500, added!

Comment: @Viki Can i use something like this?WebElement title_check= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
String strng = title_check.getText();
Assert.assertEquals(strng, cellValue);

Comment: @Ms.Salona, within the assert you just need to put two strings you want to compare. If `String strng = title_check.getText()` is what you want to validate with cell value then it is totally fine.